# override jquery theme with custom css

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am not a web designer. I'm trying to help out a friend.

In building this site, I've decided to implement some jquery to facilitate some smooth transitions between page elements. The problem I run into is that in order for the jquery to function, I must include http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css in my code, which overrides my custom css. The specific problem is that it reformats the text in my hyperlinks and it looks awful.

What is the easiest way to prevent the jquery css from overriding my custom css? I've been reading about themeroller, but after all the work I've already done, even that is looking too complicated.

Comment: If I remember correctly, making your CSS [!important](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) will do the trick.

Comment: Apparently short answers can get converted into comments. That's a good thing to remember.

Comment: I've already flagged everything in my own CSS as !important with no effect.

Comment: Can we have an example of the code? Perhaps a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Are you including this style sheet before or after yours?

Comment: I've linked it in my html both before and after my own with no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers state, you can simply add `!important` to any css style you definitely want to use (like yours vs. jquery's). That should do the trick. But this is quite tedious when done for your whole css document.

**First thing you can do**

is to make sure your css is **included after** jquery's. This will force your css stylings over jquery's as they are included last. And hope it works. (see [Two css files defining same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417287/two-css-files-defining-same-class))

**Next thing you can do**

is to play around with jquery's css sheet. What happens if you include a file `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css` that is actually empty? Will jquery work? What if you just delete all css code that touches your stuff? What exceptions are logged in the developer tools?

**Finally you can**

go the hard (but recommended) way of putting all the css stuff (yours and jquery's) together in a [**custom jquery theme**](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/themes.html). This can mean a lot of reordering and replanning, but once you've done it, jquery should be no problem any more.

Comment: So in the end what worked was adding the element .ui-link to my css file with !important after those lines that I needed. Even if my css was linked last, it still wouldn't work without !important. I'm just linking to an online css rather than copying it to my server - I don't know what the best practice is for using jquery. Site url: http://www.arrington-photography.com

I guess adding the .ui-link to my css is what they mean by specificity?

I am so not a web designer. Now ask me to configure spam filtering on an Exchange server, that I can do.

Comment: Adding the `.ui-link` looks like just the right way. Good that it works now. (oh, and by the way: you could *accept my answer* so that others with the same problem find the solution easier)

Comment: I think it was the combination that worked. Linking my CSS last, adding the jquery element id to my own css, and marking it as important.

I do appreciate everyone's help :)

Comment: After several months of "helping out friends", I'm apparently a web designer. And I can look at this now and definitely say this is the right answer. I had `.ui`, but jquery had `.ui-link` which was more specific, regardless of load order. I had to override it by adding it to my own CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` in your css. May i think these will help u.

> CSS rules marked !important take precedence over later rules.

Ex:

```
#example p {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

[**Reference**](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/)

Comment: While `!important` might work., I would caution against its use and only use it if all other attempts have failed.  Use the cascade and specificity which are inherent to CSS to control your styles .  Using `!important` goes against this flow and if your not careful can lead to a hard to manage style sheet and even more `!important` declarations snowballing the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` in your existing css style.

## Example

```
#yourCustomID {
    width: 500px !important;
    background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your css file is loaded after the jqm-css

for instance you have this navbar

```
<div data-role="navbar" id="foo1" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="toList" data-icon="custom-settings"   data-iconshadow="false" data-transition="fade"></a></li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

you can style it like

```
 #foo1 .ui-btn{
height:45px;
}

.ui-icon-custom-settings {
background: url(../images/custom-icon) no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```