# datetime picker incompatible with FLATUI Free Version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just start using bootstrap and I have used https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI as flat UI design.

Currently I just added https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker as my datetimepicker. But it seem both css have been fighting with each other.

I able to click on the button of datatimepicker. It straight display the time at the textbox without letting me choose from the dropdown menu (that it should appear). I believe flat UI from designmodo have override the dropdown menu for specific class but too bad I have no idea which part to fix this problem.

[image: Default DateTimePicker without FLAT UI design css]

[image: With FLAT UI design css]

Anyone have met the same problem like me? Please guide me from here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got your answer. But I faced similar issue. I am using https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker. Components aren't the same, but I faced same issue. After some analysis, there is a css conflict. Both of them create class .input-group-date. So there's no fight as you  mention, but based on css rules([Two css files defining same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417287/two-css-files-defining-same-class)), order of css files will define which class will stylize the component and you will have one of components not working properly.